# Python Mocking - How to patch a variable inside a function

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, patch

I've never patched a variable before, is it even possible? The code is as follows:

script.py

```
import win32gui

def code():
"""
Fetch Window handles by name and set the "test" handle to the foreground
"""

    open_window = False
    top_windows = []

    while open_window == False:

        # Iterate through Window handles and add them into the "top_windows" list
        win32gui.EnumWindows(windowEnumerationHandler, top_windows)

        # Find "test" handle and set it to the foreground then break loop
        for window in top_windows:

            if "test" in window[1]:
                win32gui.ShowWindow(window[0],5)
                win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(window[0])
                open_window = True
                break

            else:     # Keeping looping until "test" handle has loaded and
                pass  # switch to it in the event it hasn't loaded up yet
```

test_script.py

```
import code

from unittest.mock import patch

def test_code():

  # Question pertains to this line of code. How would I write it? If possible?
  with patch(~~~ patch top_windows and give it a value of [("dummy","test")]
             so code doesn't loop forever ~~~),\

       patch('code.win32gui.SetForegroundWindow') as patch_1,\
       patch('code.win32gui.ShowWindow) as patch_2,\
       patch('code.win32gui.EnumWindows)as patch_3:

           code()

   assert patch_1.call_count == 1
   assert patch_2.call_count == 2
   assert patch_3.call_count == 3
```

Without patching the variable "top_windows", this code will just indefinitely loop. Anyway I can patch it or a workaround of some sort?

Comment: You can't mock a function's local variable.

Comment: Thanks! Nice to clearly know that its not possible.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Quirky fix but I got it to work by turning the variable into a function.